# How to prevent unwanted indicators from appearing on the panel

Tags: unity, indicator, panel

I had a problem on Ubuntu 14.04, where some of my Unity indicators were not appearing (such as Dropbox, Caffeine, my-weather-indicator). I somehow managed to fix my problem, but new panel indicators now appear, the classic Skype, Thunderbird, Empathy, which are not Unity-styled.

How can I get rid of them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Dash, search for Startup Applications, and uncheck those apps that you don't want starting automatically, like Skype

Comment: No, I do want them to start automatically. But skype, thunderbird and empathy are integrated in my messaging indicator, and I do not want them to appear twice (the "non-unity" colored indicators)

Comment: hmmm,  the only other thing i could think of is `/etc/xdg/autostart` directory; there's some indicators that start through there. There's also `~/.config/` and `~/.config/autostart` . check there

Comment: Thanks, I checked. I don't think it has something to do with autostart, because regardlesss of when I open those apps (thunderbird, skype), I am shown the colored icon, thing which did not happen before. So unity must have blocked those indicators/tray icons somehow before, and now doesn't.